# javascript functions conflicts

Tags: javascript, colorbox, news-ticker

I have these scripts for my website but only one function works at a time, whichever code is close to head tag works fine. what is a solution to work both function with out any conflict.

CODE IS GIVEN BELOW:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="demo_files/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="demo_files/jquery.vticker-min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
    $(function(){
        $('#news-container').vTicker({ 
            speed: 500,
            pause: 3000,
            animation: 'fade',
            mousePause: false,
            showItems: 3
        });
            $('#news-container1').vTicker({
            speed: 700,
            pause: 4000,
            animation: 'fade',
            mousePause: false,
            showItems: 1
        });
    });
    </script> 
    <style type="text/css">
    body{ font-family:Verdana, Arial, serif; font-size:14px;}
    </style>
    <link media="screen" rel="stylesheet" href="colorbox.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="jquery.colorbox-min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function()
    {
        $(window).bind('load', 
            function(e) 
            {
                $.colorbox({opacity:0.3, href:"offer.html"}); 
            });
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: Please provide a minimal example with this issue. Maybe using [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Long Answer:** It's because you are including jQuery twice, once right at the top, and again about half way down (a minified version).

The second time you include the library, the $ object will be redefined, overriding the existing instance. Any code attached the $ object when this happend, such as events and plugins, will be lost.

**Short Answer:** Remove the second copy of jQuery, it should work then.

Comment: beeglebug thanks for the reply can u paste the edited code part. i am a novice in java. anyway i am trying myself too. if works out will inform :D thanks in advance

Comment: @Matthias  as I said earliier i am a novice and dont know how to deal with jsFiddle. it would b gr8 if you could edit my code as suggested by beeglebug. I tried but in vain

Comment: It should be as easy as removing the line which says "<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>". Everything should work once that is gone.

Comment: Also, it's "Javascript", not "Java", there is a big difference between the two, and some people get a bit upset when the two are confused :)

Comment: Beeglebug THANK YOU FROM THE BOTTOM OF MY HEART! Its works perfectly now. You know this was my first ever online help post. Glad that it solved. I spend abt two weeks to get sort out this and within a couple of days it solved thru stackoverflow.com Kudos! [thanks for the java and javascript info i wasnt aware that too]. THANKS ALL!